# Access Network folder with Username and Password in Java

Tags: java, java-io

Can you please help me on this.

I want to access the network folder that requires username and password,
How can I access it programmatically by supplying username and password   in   JAVA?

Answer (score 1):

If by "network folder" you mean a "windows shared folder" use [JCIFS](https://jcifs.samba.org/), if you mean some other [shared resource](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_resource) please specify which.

Example from the API :

```
import jcifs.smb.*;

jcifs.Config.setProperty( "jcifs.netbios.wins", "192.168.1.220" );
NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication("domain", "username", "password");
SmbFileInputStream in = new SmbFileInputStream("smb://host/c/My Documents/somefile.txt", auth);
```